# I try to createOrUpdate a realm object from json. the json is in the object but all fields are null

Tags: android, realm

My code:

```
AppCFG appCFG = new AppCFG();

    if(jsonToParse != null) {

        Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(AppController.getInstance());

        appCFG.setOid(ParserJsonMethods.getOid(jsonToParse));

        appCFG.setBaseResourceUrl(jsonToParse.optString(AppCFGContract.BASE_RESOURCE_URL));
        appCFG.setClientName(jsonToParse.optString(AppCFGContract.CLIENT_NAME));
        appCFG.setBucketName(jsonToParse.optString(AppCFGContract.BUCKET_NAME));
        appCFG.setConfigUpdatedOn(StringConvertions.stringDateToMillis(jsonToParse.optString(AppCFGContract.CONFIGURATION_UPDATED_ON)));
        appCFG.setDefaultOutputVideoMaxFps(jsonToParse.optInt(AppCFGContract.DEFAULT_OUTPUT_VIDEO_MAX_FPS));
        appCFG.setLatestPackagePublishedOn(StringConvertions.stringDateToMillis(jsonToParse.optString(AppCFGContract.LATEST_PACKAGE_PUBLISHED_ON)));
        appCFG.setOnboardingPassed(jsonToParse.optBoolean(AppCFGContract.ONBOARDING_PASSED));
        appCFG.setOnboardingUsingPackage(jsonToParse.optString(AppCFGContract.ONBOARDING_USING_PACKAGE));
        appCFG.setPrefferedFootageOID(jsonToParse.optString(AppCFGContract.PREFFERED_FOOTAGE_OID));
        appCFG.setTweaks(jsonToParse.optString(AppCFGContract.TWEAKS));
        appCFG.setUploadUserContent(jsonToParse.optString(AppCFGContract.UPLOAD_USER_CONTENT));
        appCFG = parseMixedScreen(appCFG, jsonToParse);

        realm.beginTransaction();

        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(appCFG);

        realm.commitTransaction();
```

The result of pulling all results:
[image: All fields empty json attached]

All fields are empty.. but somehow the json is attached to the object.. What am I doing wrong??

EDIT:
When I do result.getBaseResourceUrl() after pulling all results and opening this result (the result from the image), for instance, I get back a good answer which is:http://blah.blah. but when I try to get results from realm based on baseResourceUrl = "http://blah.blah" I get back nothing...

Answer (score 1):

Realm uses a zero-copy architecture with proxy objects. This means that all your data is always kept inside our internal storage engine in C++ and not actually copied to Java. This also means that Realm doesn't really use the Java variables and as such they always have uninitialised value when looking at them through a debugger (`null` for objects, `0` for ints, `""` for strings)

You can see your object is really a `<yourtype>RealmProxy`. What this proxy class does is overriding all getters and setters to access the data in C++ instead of Java. So if you use the normal getters you can access you data. The proxy also creates a proper toString() method which is why your popup shows the correct output.

Comment: But I do AppCFG appCFG1 = realm.where(AppCFG.class)
                .equalTo(AppCFGContract.BaseResourceUrl, "http://blah.blah")
                .findFirst();                                                                                                and get nothing back...

Comment: That should work provided that BaseResourceUrl is ```baseResourceUrl``` and that field contains the string ```blah.blah```. In your screenshot your url is ```http://blah.blah```.

Comment: Have you tried using findAll() instead and see if the object exists at all? That way you can also verify the value of baseResourceUrl

Comment: yes I wrote that in my edit, I did findAll and pulled all results. but searching by one field returned nothing

Comment: Ok, without seeing more of your code it is hard to tell what could be wrong. Please create an issue on our GitHub page, preferably with some sample code so we can reproduce the issue: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues